# OPENLDAP: password policy overlap, how to assign to a specific OU

Tags: security, openldap, policy, password-policy

I need to set password policy only to a specific OU, and it will be applied to all users that will be crated/moved in this OU.

I have OPENLDAP 2.4.44 installed on CentOS 7, and I configured it in this way (I used this guide: https://ktree.com/blog/OpenLDAP-password-policy-implementatio-on-ubuntu.html):

**Step1.** Enable policy Overlay, It can be done by installing the schema.

```
$ ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.ldif
```

For Verification, whether it is done or not

```
[root@TST-LDAP01]# ldapsearch -Q -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=schema,cn=config dn
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={1}cosine,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={2}nis,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={3}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={4}ppolicy,cn=schema,cn=config
```

**Step2.** We need to write to the directory where are all policies will be filename: policies_1.ldif

```
$ vim policies_1.ldif
 dn: ou=Policies,cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com
 objectClass: top
 objectClass: organizationalUnit
 ou: Policies
 description: Password policy config files
```

To apply to the directory:

```
$ ldapadd -D cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com -W -f policies_1.ldif
```

**Step3.** Now, We load the Modules handling the policies.

```
$ vim policy_module.ldif
 dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
 changetype: modify
 add: olcModuleLoad
 olcModuleLoad: ppolicy
```

To apply to the directory :

```
$ ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f policy_module.ldif
```

For verification, modules loaded?

```
[root@TST-LDAP01]# ldapsearch -Q -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=module{0},cn=config
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{0}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap
olcModuleLoad: {0}syncprov.la
olcModuleLoad: {1}ppolicy
```

**Step4.** Now tell directory where to look for the policies.

```
$ vim policy_overlay.ldif
dn: olcOverlay={1}ppolicy,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcPPolicyConfig
olcOverlay: {1}ppolicy
olcPPolicyDefault: cn=DefaultPPolicy,ou=Policies,cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com
```

To apply to the directory

```
$ ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f policy_overlay.ldif
```

For Verification, Overlays in use

```
[root@TST-LDAP01]# ldapsearch -Q -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=mydomain,dc=com
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com
olcRootPW: {SSHA}1AMIpQs6xbFa8wYre5rdBGm+fCmTCVXz
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq,pres
olcDbIndex: ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname eq,pres,sub

dn: olcOverlay={0}ppolicy,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcPPolicyConfig
olcOverlay: {0}ppolicy
olcPPolicyDefault: cn=DefaultPPolicy,ou=Policies,cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=c
 om
```

**Step5.** Now we can create default policy objects.

```
$ vim Default_Policies.ldif
dn: cn=DefaultPPolicy,ou=Policies,cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com
cn: DefaultPPolicy
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: device
objectClass: top
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdMaxAge: 2592000
pwdExpireWarning: 2160000
pwdInHistory: 3
pwdCheckQuality: 1
pwdMinLength: 8
pwdMaxFailure: 3
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 30
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
```

To apply to the directory

```
$ ldapadd -D cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com -W -f Default_Policies.ldif
```

For Verification

```
[root@TST-LDAP01]# ldapsearch -Q -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=DefaultPPolicy,ou=Policies,cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com
dn: cn=DefaultPPolicy,ou=Policies,cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com
cn: DefaultPPolicy
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: device
objectClass: top
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdMaxAge: 2592000
pwdExpireWarning: 2160000
pwdInHistory: 3
pwdCheckQuality: 1
pwdMinLength: 8
pwdMaxFailure: 3
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 30
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
```

Now is it possible to set Default_Policies only to ou=ExternalUsers,cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com and all new users have this settings?

Thanks
Marco

Answer (score 2):

sorry, can't comment due to my reputation score but a similar question was answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/830147/openldap-password-policy-for-a-group

The following may help but it is user specific:

Create custom policy for example:

```
dn: cn=pwdLockoutDuration,ou=Policies,dc=test,dc=com
objectClass: device
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: top
cn: pwdLockoutDuration
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdExpireWarning: 500
pwdMaxAge: 600
pwdMaxFailure: 3
```

Then add a subentry to the user:

```
dn: cn=test4,ou=Users,dc=test,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: pwdPolicySubentry
pwdPolicySubentry:  cn=pwdLockoutDuration,ou=Policies,dc=test,dc=com
```